# In Typescript, How do you define a type that is made up of a property from another type?

Tags: typescript

Still trying to wrap my head around typed languages but let's say i have the following

```
export interface Person {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const persons: Array<Person> = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'bar',
  },
];

const foobar = persons.map((person: Person) => person.id);
```

What is the correct type definition for foobar? `Array<Person['id']>` appears to work, but i want to make it clear that this is an array of `Person.id` and my editor reports that it is just `Number[]`. I know this is correct, but i wanted to know if it is possible to make it more clear than that?

Comment: But person ID is a number, defined as per your interface... so, I’m not really sure what you’re trying to get at. It can’t get any more specific.

Comment: i would like to know that foobar is an array of person id's not an array of numbers. For example if i hover on persons it tells me it's an array of persons, not an array of Objects. It would just be helpful for me to hover on foobar and it tell me that it is an array of person.id but im starting to think this might not be possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is essentially a type whose values are all of type `number`, but which is named `PersonId` or something similar, indicating that its purpose is different from the type `number`.

Typescript has a [structural type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system), so types with the same structure (e.g. two `number` types) are equal. That means the `PersonId` type will always resolve to just `number` unless it has a different structure. One way to do this is to say `PersonId` has a property distinguishing it from `number`; this property doesn't need to exist on actual `PersonId` values, which are numbers, but it tells the compiler that this type is not the same as `number`.

```js
export type PersonId = number & { __brand: 'PersonId' };

export interface Person {
  id: PersonId;
  name: string;
}
```

A slight downside is that we need to use a type assertion to say that a `number` value is actually a `PersonId` value:

```js
const persons: Array<Person> = [
  {
    id: 1 as PersonId,
    name: 'foo',
  },
  {
    id: 2 as PersonId,
    name: 'bar',
  },
];
```

If you need to write many `Person` object literals, you could avoid writing this type assertion many times using a helper function to create them.

The upside is that you can write `PersonId` in type annotations, and not only will the compiler preserve the distinction between the `number` and `PersonId` types; it will also prevent you accidentally assigning some other `number` where a `PersonId` is expected, since the only way to get a value of type `PersonId` (without an intentional type assertion) is to access a `Person` object's `id` property.

```js
// PersonId[] is not number[]
const foobar: PersonId[] = persons.map((person: Person) => person.id);

function logId(id: PersonId): void {
    console.log(id);
}

logId(foobar[0]); // ok
logId(1 + 2 + 3); // type error
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcAKwoGcIDsCSAJnALxy4CuAtgEaZwBkcA3nAPps1QCGuhAXHADkGbHiJC4AXwDcAKDmhIsOAEtcMTADNuAY1SicuFnLhqB6TEaLyzublWCCsMKOoDm8qQt14XcFDFcLEEAQSgeRAAeQzwAPlI4AG1TEzMzVQsARjhuLEsgogAaVLsHJ2EtCAghErMpOrT0zMEAJlz82IJCRrLHQSEabiha1Ia5AF15OV9g+CqIIahBLqIkicTAoywAOipuMAAKQ628Fas8AEpSBNPcHczL6a0KXF0YVTw4ABsIdyJDi0CtZCJdBAA3CCZJpmWY4b7AHa-dyA0FeBTIgELJZJAAMEyecAA9ES4BAANZyTGEQ45ADUcHaDIAzISSQhkKhMFBoHIgA)

Comment: What if `brand` is made optional, so that type assertions are unnecessary? Will this break something?

Comment: @Cerberus Yes, you can make `__brand` an optional property if you want, then the compiler will still preserve the difference between PersonId and number, but you don't need type assertions to say that numbers are PersonId values. The downside is you won't get an error if you provide a non-PersonId number where a PersonId is expected; up to you whether that matters or not. I prefer making it non-optional because it more closely resembles custom number types in languages like e.g. Ada where you have to explicitly cast to say that a number is known to be suitable for a particular context.

Answer (score 1):

Great question!

For both `Array<Person['id']>` and `Array<Number>` [view here](https://ts-ast-viewer.com/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgBTQGcIk4BvAKDkQBMAuOJAVwFsAjNAbmqc1eCMiMKMgDmPAL6VK2UsLhhi8xgEEoUTAE8APISgkkAPjgBeOAG1eVGjQQM4ARgA0vGkn6C4AcnQQI3q40kkEUbnSMAEyh7p6M3uyYUIG8IZQAujyy8vB+EIlQahraespIFt723ukm5koG8gB0rJhgABRt9YaM+oYAlGYmXaSN9n08ckgKeQWRRZq6AHJsnFC1imVEza0dw0g9ZQOmQ2WjtONAA) 
As we can see, both inferrers to the underlying type of `Number[]`

However, the advantage of using `Array<Person['id']>`is it keeps an explicit reference to the underlying type for `Person['id']`

This means that by using `Array<Person['id']>`, you would not have to worry about maintaining the type if `Person['id']`'s definition ever changes.

e.g if `Person['id']` has been refactored into a `string` type.
`Array<Person['id']>` would gets parsed into `string[]`. however this would not happen if we similarly defined `foobar` as `Number[]` since it doesn't maintain the referrence to `Person['id']`'s type. [example for this case](https://ts-ast-viewer.com/#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgBTQGcIk4BvAKDkQBMAuOImKZAcwG5q4lMBbYI2asknSgF9KlbKWZwwxWYwCCUKJgCeAHkJQSSAHxwAvHADa3KjRoIGcAOQBGewBpuNXgMb30ECK+5xNxora1tvACYA6x5+QQcAI0woaLggygBdLmlZeF8IJKgVNU0dRSQze1t7DKNTBT1ZADo+TDAACnaG-UZdfQBKEyNu0ibbfq4ZJDl8woji9W0AOQBXPgS0Ovlyoha2zpGkXvLB42HysdoJoA)

[image]

Comment: not quite was i was looking for but this is still a good tidbit to know. thank you!